# Распознавание  простых жестов на Android

Tags: распознавание, android, java

Для тестового задания нужно написать программу для Андроида, распознавание простых жестов. существует 2 области экрана, на одной выводиться сфотографированный жест ладони с камеры либо галереи, на второй области выводиться распознанный символ. например азбука глухонемых.

Помогите пожалуйста литературой по этому вопросу. Где можно почитать об распознавании, как это реализовать на Андроиде и тп.

Comment: т.е. надо сфоткать руку и попробовать распознать ее жест?

Comment: да, именно так

Comment: Нужно нафотаграфировать много-много жестов, классифицировать их всех вручную. А потом попытаться обучить нейронную сеть. Правда, если рука будет составлять несколько процентов изображения, а на фоне будет ещё много других изображений, то задача очень сильно усложняется.

Comment: нужно найти готовое апи

Answer (score 2):

openCV

Answer (score 1):

По поводу готового Api - очень мало шансов, что вы это найдете.

Правильный вариант - это создать свою нейронную сеть. Потом обучить ее на многочисленных жестах, чтобы она начала понимать их.

Как вариант взгляните на приложения в маркете, которые способны расспознавать только свои  "маркеры".

По сути, вам надо сделать так, чтобы приложение распознавало жесты, как эти "маркеры", а без правильно обученой нейронной сети (тк жесты не "макркеры", и простыми методами их не различишь) тут не обойдешься.

[Почитать про распознавание "маркеров"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135659/)

Answer (score 0):

Во первых вам нужно убедиться что жесты показывает именно человек а не другие сучества (нимфы-хоббиты, мало ли...) - для этого нужно определить если ли челлицо в кадре. Неплохо с этой задачей справляется OpenCV - https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html
Однако еще лучше DLIB - http://dlib.net/face_detector.py.html
Масса других примеров есть, поищите - python, C++, java

Затем нужно взять фрагмент кожи лица (лучше всего в районе щеки, так как там нет волос и не закрывается аксессуарами) и найти цветовые доминанты (K-means clustering) - https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d5c/tutorial_py_kmeans_opencv.html
Удобно для этой цели использовать цветовые схемы Lab, HSV/HSL - в opencv можно конвертировать из BGR в любую.

Затем с помощью OpenCV InRange отфильтровать исходное изображение по всем K цветовым доминантам - получите K бинарных масок, их нужно объединить с помощью bitwise_or. 
Теперь в областях с белыми битами ищите руки - они должны быть где-то соразмерно недалеко от лица. А дальше всё будет зависеть от ловкости Ваших рук (никакого мошенства) - для анализа позы руки применение CNN или другой подходящей нейросети уже вполне соразмерно задаче.

Неплохой материал  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xML2S6bvMwI - под видео ссылка на статью.

Comment: да... из цветовых доминант неплохо бы удалить оттенки серого, если они там окажутся... ну и ваще... задачка такая, потребует несколько внимания и серого вещества ;-) У Дачи!

Comment: И таки да - этот подход не будет работать если рука в перчатке/рукавице, ну и желательно тоже чтобы лицо было не в балаклаве ;-)